# Fail to connect to database C# VS to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

Whenever I try to run this script in Visual Studio It fails to connect to the server (and go down to catch). I am trying to input data into a database in SQL Express. The debugger shows no error messages. I'm pretty new at C#/SQL if that wasn't already obvious!

```
SqlConnection cnSqlSvr;
sSql = @"DataSource = computername\sqlexpress" +
@"Initial Catalog=FAI;" +      
@"Integrated Security=SSPI;";
try 
{
   cnSqlSvr = new SqlConnection(sSql);
   cnSqlSvr.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error");
   return;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon between `DataSource` and `Initial Catalog`. Also you are not utilizing the exception object `ex` in `catch` block, Use it, you will know what actually went wrong with your connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forget to use `;` between the first and the second strings.

Moreover you can change your code this way to see what is the problem

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   return;
}
```

Comment: I was messing around with it for a while and accidentally removed the semicolon. Putting it back doesn't solve the issue though

Comment: @alex_stock have you tried connecting using a user and password?

Comment: I added

    @"UserID=Rich" +
    @"Password=12345";

to sSql... still showing up as "Error"

Comment: You also need a space between Data and Source: `@"Data Source = computername\sqlexpress"`

Comment: Did you use `ex.Message` to show the exact message?